# Always add trailing slash in url

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC with Spring Controllers. I want to always add a trailing slash if it is not present at the end of the url. How can I do this?

```
www.mysite.com/something -> www.mysite.com/something/
www.mysite.com/somethingelse/ -> www.mysite.com/somethingelse/
```

Comment: How are you running this app? Tomcat, Jetty,  standalone or embedded?

Comment: @diginoise Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using an `HandlerInterceptor` :

The interceptor will check if the request URI ends with a slash.
If it does, the request is processed, if not, the response is redirected with the same URI with a trailing slash.
In the example below, I ignore requests with a query string, since I don't kow how you want to handle this case.

The interceptor :

```java
@Component
public class TrailingSlashInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(request.getQueryString()) && !request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/")) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURL().append("/").toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Register and map the interceptor in your config :

```java
@Autowired
private TrailingSlashInterceptor trailingSlashInterceptor;

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addInterceptor(trailingSlashInterceptor)
        .addPathPatterns("/**")
        .excludePathPatterns("/static/**");
}
```

I noticed that in your JSP, if you have some, you have to make URL start with a slash eg: `<c:url value="/clients" />`

Using this method, all requests that have no trailing slash will be temporary redirected (302) toward the same URI with a trailing slash.